# Is Possible to integrate small cocos2d-x 3.2 game inside existing IOS application using swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, cocos2d-x-3.x, xcode8.2

Hello friends is it possible to create a game using cocos2dx 3.x , Swift.If this is possible than how can i integrate my game inside my native IOS application using swift3.Please Guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's quite possible since cocos2d-x will work on a OpenGLES view. And also xCode understands C++. 
But it will be a bit tricky to add ; you need to handle all of build configurations with large cocos2d-x library etc.